# Merging two objects and removing properties which are not present from the original

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I've got a front-end app in which the user can add/remove fields from their profile. I'm trying to create a PUT request to the API and usually I'd just _.merge(original, req.body) but the updated object has several properties removed from the object which is not on the original object.

Is there any way to merge the objects and have the fields which have been removed on the new object, also removed from the original one - while maintaining the original object and merging values which are present on both objects (it's a mongoose model with id properties and such that I need to keep)

Thank you!

Comment: Post your request body sample let's see do we have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `defaults` or `defaultsDeep` [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#defaults) plus `pick` [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick).

For example:

```
const original = {check: 1};
const anotherObj = {check: 3, data: 2};
const resultMerge = _.defaults(anotherObj, original);
const result = _.pick(resultMerge, _.keys(original));

// result => {check: 3};
```

Comment: I don't know why this is accepted, because when I run it I get `{ check: 3, data: 2 }`

Comment: You're totally right. Sorry that I missed that part. I updated the answer to fit the description.

Comment: I am not sure that this satisfies the OP's answer, because he wrote that he wanted to have the fields removed from the original object. `_.pick` returns a new object, doesn't modify the original one. And I'm only saying all this, because I'm also looking for an answer to the same problem, and the one above doesn't cut it, for me at least.

Comment: Honestly the description is not clear, you wanna update both objects with the same keys but different values? which one is supposed to overwrite the other values?

Comment: Assume `orig = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }, other = { 'a': 3, c: '4' }`, then after `_.fn(orig, other)` => `orig = {  'a': 3, c: '4' }`. It looks like `orig = other` but without changing the pointer to point to the `other` object, just copying over the values one by one, deleting all properties not in `other` and adding all properties in `other`.

Comment: then do the same and overwrite the original, that's it:

  let original = { a: 1, b: 2 };
  let other = { a: 3, c: 4 };
  original = other = _.pick(_.defaults(other, original), _.keys(original));

Comment: You are changing the `original` pointer again. Objects in JavaScript are copied by reference. When you do `orig = other` the original object pointer now points to `other` and when you point that to the result of `_.pick` it is a whole new object altogether. Whilst if you did `orig.a = other.a; delete orig.b; orig.c = other.c;` all pointers remain intact.

Comment: Then the only way is just an iteration over the keys, and you should do it manually. Do you want me to write it for you?